# MYSQL Query, Optimize LIKE and NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have a query I need to run which is currently running extremely slow.  The table I am working with has nearly 1 million records.

What I need to do is search for items with a LIKE name : Example `"SELECT name, other, stuff FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE '%some_name%'"`

In addition it has to be able to exclude certain terms with wildcards from the search results so it turns into something like this :

```
SELECT name, other, stuff 
FROM my_table 
WHERE name LIKE '%some_name%' 
AND name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE '%term1%' AND name LIKE '%term2%' AND name LIKE '%term3%')
```

To top things off, I have two INNER JOINs and I have to execute it in PHP. I have indexes on the table for relevant columns.  It is on a server that is fast for pretty much every other query I can throw at it.

The question is, is there a different method I could be using to do this type of query thats is quick?

UPDATES

This is my actual query after adding in FULLTEXT index to the chem table and trying the match function instead.  NOTE : I don't have control over table/column names.  I know they dont look nice.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX name_index ON chems (name)

SELECT f.name fname, f.state, f.city, f.id fid,
cl.alt_facilid_ida, cl.alt_facili_idb,
c.ave, c.name, c.id chem_id,
cc.first_name, cc.last_name, cc.id cid, cc.phone_work
FROM facilities f
INNER JOIN facilitlt_chemicals_c cl ON (f.id = cl.alt_facilid485ilities_ida)
INNER JOIN chems c ON (cl.alt_facili3998emicals_idb = c.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN facilities_contacts_c con ON (f.id = con.alt_facili_ida)
LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts cc ON (con.alt_facili_idb = cc.id)
WHERE match(c.name) against ('+lead -gas' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

That is just an example of a simple query.  The actual terms could be numerous.

Comment: Do you have a primary key or unique ID on my_table? IF so it would probably be quicker to do `... AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM ...`

Comment: instead of a sub select I would simply do:

WHERE name LIKE '%some_name%' 
AND name NOT LIKE '%term1%' 
AND name NOT LIKE '%term2%' 
AND name NOT LIKE '%term3%'

That would be faster.

Comment: Also, if you DO use a sub select, you should probably separate your conditions with OR instead of AND, unless they are all needed at once.

Comment: Sometimes creating a temporary table for holding your filtered rows BEFORE performing the joins, (and then joining the temporary table instead of the original one) is much, much faster than joining the huge tables.  You should benchmark it yourself.
Just don't forget to create the table with the indexes too.

Comment: I updated the description with my query.  Still very slow.   The server it self is pretty beefy, 18 gigs of ram, fast CPU, etc..

Answer (score 5):

You want to implement MySQL's full text capabilities on the columns you're searching. Read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Moreover, you probably want to do a boolean search:

```
select
    t1.name,
    t1.stuff
from
    my_table t1
where
    match(t1.name) against ('+some_name -term1 -term2 -term3' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: Might I also suggest `boolean mode` serching (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) which will add symbols such as + and - to require or exclude words. Also what is the point of the join/'not in'. This might even be able to remove the join/'not in' by saying `match(t1.name) against ('+some_name -term1 -term2')`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Great suggestion. It's been years since I've used MySQL full text searching, so thanks for filling in the gap :)

Comment: fix `against ('+some_name -term1 -term2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.

Comment: I have no added a fulltext index to my search columns and am currently running the match() function instead.   Still extremely slow. I'll post my live query I am using shortly.

Comment: @Tyler - Yes, it will be slow until you add an index to it. It's trying to go through a million strings and compare plain text. This takes awhile, typically.

Comment: @Eric I did add an index.   no = now.  It was a typo :P

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use external Full-text engine like Lucene or Sphinx. Especially if you plan to fire search queries against relatively big datasets.

In Sphinx case you can use SELECT-like syntax called SphinxQL which will do exactly as required:

```
SELECT * FROM <sphinx_index_name> WHERE MATCH('some_name -term1 -term2 -term3');
```

as described in http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax (NOT operator in your case). Plus you could enable morphology support which might be helpful as well.

You can combine MySQL and Sphinx queries with http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxse