# optimizing like queries mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am doing a lot of like queries on medium text columns in mysql table. I have the following schema:

```
table events
* response MEDIUMTEXT
* request MEDIUMTEXT
* user_id
```

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM events wHERe user_id = X and response LIKE ...
```

I can put an index on user_id column to make the query run faster (that's still leaves to processes millions of rows), but obviously not on the response column.

What is a solution I can adopt to optimize like queries in mysql?

Should I consider another database solution like elastic searches, for example?

Comment: If you have an index on user_id that is already good to reduce the subset of rows on which `LIKE` will run with an `AND`

Comment: have you heard about fulltext search?

Answer (score 0):

If you can put an index on the `user_id` column, then your query will run faster and will perform an optimized search on these identifiers.

To solve the performance problem of `LIKE`, if your query will always involve a text search and this query isn't just a try, you can use the [FULL-TEXT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_search) search feature. Further info about the FULL-TEXT search in MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). There's an example of using FULL-TEXT in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717188/mysql-query-optimize-like-and-not-in?rq=1) of SO.

Answer (score 0):

If the search queries are similar you can also use tags as stackoverflow does.